# Joining elements of respective 1D lists inside 2D list in python

Tags: python, list, 2d

I have a 2D list. I want to merge the first elements of each of the 1D list.
For eg.
`[[40,0,0],[41,5,10],[3,10,30]]`
My output list should look like:
`[[40,0,0,41],[5,10,3,10],[30,0,0,0]]`
I want all the elements to have length of 4 by taking elements from the next element , to achieve consistent length of 4, and when elements get over, append zeroes to achieve length of 4

Comment: This is not merging the first elements ...

Comment: exactly @DaniMesejo you need to edit your question with the proper output.

Comment: @coderoftheday Accepted, sorry for the mix -up. I edited it

Comment: The second item in your expected output takes 2 items from the next element. Is this what you want? Please reconstruct your question, as it looks some more complex now. You want each item to have length 4 by using items of next elements?

Comment: @ IoaTzimas, yes i want it to have lenght of 4 ..that is actually my main motto...each element should have lenght of 4 by using items from next elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need a new list that will have items with 4 elements each, taken from the chain of the original list. If this is the case, here is a solution:

```
l=[[40,0,0],[41,5,10],[3,10,30]]
m=sum(l, [])

res=[m[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(m), 4)]
res[-1]=res[-1]+[0]*(4-len(res[-1]))

>>> print(res)

[[40, 0, 0, 41], [5, 10, 3, 10], [30, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks @loaTzimas for the help and the initial idea how to proceed

Comment: You are welcome. Just change the title and description of your question to be more helpful for future readers

Comment: I have edited my question...some tweak is needed in your logic to achieve that i guess...sorry for the mix up @ IoaTzimas

Answer (score 1):

For what you describe, for a list of arbitrary length, the following should work:

```
big_list = [[40,0,0],[41,5,10],[3,10,30]]
# Iterates through the sublists (except for the final one)
for index in range(len(big_list)-1):
    # Redefines a sublist to have the the first element of the next, on the end
    big_list[index].append(big_list[index+1][0])
    # Redefines the next sublist to have the first element removed
    big_list[index+1] = big_list[index+1][1:]
print(big_list)
```

Comment: @Alexander..Thanks for the logic...i was missing to redefine the next sublist to have the first element removed

Answer (score 1):

Flatten and then iterate in chunks (using the [grouper recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html)):

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    """Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"""
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return [list(t) for t in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)]


lst = [[40,0,0],[41,5,10],[3,10,30]]
flat = [e for l in lst for e in l]

res = grouper(flat, 4, fillvalue=0)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[40, 0, 0, 41], [5, 10, 3, 10], [30, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: i was unaware of the zip_longest module. Your logic works like charm, but i will need my time to understand it. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

Make it one whole list, append remaining zeros, then create four sublists

```
l = [[40,0,0],[41,5,10],[3,10,30]]

l = [x for i in l for x in i]

[l.append(0) for x in range(16 - len(l))]

new = [[l[x*count] for x in range(4)] for count in range(1,5)]

print(new)

>>> [[40, 0, 0, 41], [40, 0, 5, 3], [40, 41, 3, 0], [40, 5, 30, 0]]
```